# VB6 - IMGSCAN.ocx - TWAIN in Kodak i2600 Scanner

Tags: vb6, twain, image-scanner

We have an VB6 application which uses IMGSCAN, IMGEDIT controls for scanning in HP Scanner (flatbed). Now we have new kodak i2600 scanner (ADF). When we try to access the new Kodak scanner through TWAIN, its hangs.

Kodak scanner product manual says it supports TWAIN and IMGSCAN, IMGEDIT controls is also TWAIN compatible.

Anyone can help us on this ? Is it possible to use IMGSCAN, IMGEDIT control to invoke TWAIN of below version

Twain: 12.12

VB6 code that we use is,

```
ImgScan1.CloseScanner

ImgScan1.ShowSelectScanner
ImgScan1.OpenScanner

ImgScan1.SetPageTypeCompressionOpts SmallestFile, ColorPal8Bit, JPEGCompression, JPEGLowHigh

ImgScan1.StartScan
ImgScan1.StopScan
ImgEdit1.Image = ImgScan1.Image
ImgEdit1.Page = ImgEdit1.PageCount

ImgThumbnail1.Image = ImgEdit1.Image
ImgEdit1.Display

ImgEdit1.SaveAs App.Path & "\testsize.tif", 1, 6, 6, 256
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the imgscan method ShowSelectScanner to select a different interface on the scanner that will work with imgscan. Many, if not most, scanners support more than one interface. You might also try initializing some of the scanning properties. And, it might be necessary to call .OpenScanner before .StartScan.

Comment: I have updated the exact code that I have used. If I choose TWAIN, Scanner initiates the scanning process, but after scanning control doesn't come back from the device to the code.

Comment: Is there only one choice on SelectScanner?

Comment: Also, you might try a color setting other than ColorPal8Bit.

Comment: ShowSelectScanner shows only two, one "Kodak i2000" (Twain) and another "WIA - Kodak i2000". I tried changing colorPal8Bit to others even then same result, scanner hangs

Comment: Same result for Twain and WIA? Either should work (theoretically).

Comment: WIA works fine, but as its ADF scanner, problem is the page size can be set once at starting of scanning. For example if I set it as "Legal" Size and scan mix of Leagal and A4 pages, all A4 pages are scanned with legal size and excess blocks are in black color. To avoid this page size should be automatically detected. Im unable to set this property in VB6 for this IMGSCAN control.

Comment: Sounds like a Twain driver incompatibility. I'd check with the manufacturer, and try various settings for a workaround.

Comment: You can use [Twack](http://www.twain.org/scannerdriverdevelopers/specification-and-tools.html) to test with your Kodak TWAIN driver and verify if it's the TWAIN driver issue.